# `which python` points to the python I want, but `python` runs the wrong version

Tags: macos, shell, python, macports, which

I want to use python24 provided by ports, so I've installed it, and `python_select -s` shows that the version I want is indeed selected. Running `which python` gives `/opt/local/bin/python`, and running `/opt/local/bin/python` gives me the version I want. However when I run `python` from the shell, I get the `/usr/bin/python` version instead. I don't have a python alias.

Here's the situation in a nutshell:

1. I believe the path is set up sensibly, and `which python` seems to confirm this.
2. `alias` only returns 1 entry, which is something unrelated to this.

Nevertheless, running `python` from the bash shell gives me the wrong python!

I'm kind of stumped! What am I overlooking?

Comment: You did check your path to see which comes first: /usr/bin or /opt/local/bin ?

Comment: yep, path was fine, as described below it was a matter of bash having stale information; the hash -d fixed it.

Comment: Next time, try the Bash builtin `type -a` instead of the external `which` (you'll still need to do `hash`)

Comment: I'm not sure if `type -a` does the trick, maybe `hash -t` instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `hash -d python`. This will tell bash to forget where it last saw the python executable.

Comment: Wow that worked! Was about a minute from wiping out my MacOS install and doing a clean install since it was stuck at 2.5 and couldn't fix!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you just updated something and your bash instance has stale information about executables. Try `exec bash`.

When I:

1. Start `qqq` (`/usr/bin/qqq`) from `bash`.
2. Add something `qqq` to `/usr/local/bin/`.
3. Try to start `qqq` again in the same `bash`.

It uses the already-looked-up version (`/usr/bin/qqq`)

However when I restart the bash, it looks for `qqq` again and gets `/usr/local/bin/qqq`.

Comment: Thanks Vi, what you suggested also worked, and your explanation was helpful. I have never encountered this problem before, I always thought `which` was "authoritative".

Comment: `which` is a separate executable, not a `bash` internal command. The problem is a stale cache in `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that the script itself specifies which Python executable to run in the first line of the script.  For example, my system has Python 2.6 and 2.7 installed, and if the first line is something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/Python-2.6.8/bin/python
```

then I get Python 2.6, even though 2.7 is the system default.

The usual way to specify the default is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```